# Adding an extra key / value to a PHP array

Tags: php

I have php array that like this:

```
$categories = array (
    "audio-video" => "Audio & Video",
    "books" => "Books",
    "vehicles" => "Vehicles",
    "watches" => "Watches"
)
```

How can I add another value to each element in it so it ends up something like this:

```
$categories = array ( // For example. This isn't the right thing.
    "US01" => "audio-video" => "Audio & Video",
    "US02" => "books" => "Books",
    "US03" => "vehicles" => "Vehicles",
    "US04" => "watches" => "Watches"
)
```

Is this possible? I'd like to able to access the other values of each element using the first key. So `US01` will be `Audio & Video` or `audio-video`. Is this possible with php?

Comment: `"US01" => "audio-video" => "Audio & Video"` --- what does this mean?

Comment: it will be invalid array

Comment: It's the extra key/value I'd like to add.

Comment: @jmenezes: what does "the extra key/value" mean?

Comment: array key is always unique, this is looks wrong format you should create another array with same values with another key or use multi level array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$categories = array(
    "US01" => array("audio-video", "Audio & Video"),
    "US02" => array("books", "Books"),
    "US03" => array("vehicles", "Vehicles"),
    "US04" => array("watches", "Watches")
)
```

access via

```
$categories['US01'][0]; // audio-video
$categories['US01'][1]; // Audio & Video
```

Comment: Can I run `array_key_exists('US01',$categories)` on an array like this? Because I need to check if the key exists before I do any more processing. It does work, but I'm asking just to be sure.

Comment: @jmenezes Yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can not. All you can do is generate a new array inside like this:

```
$categories = array(
    array(
        "US01",
        "audio-video",
        "Audio & Video"
    ),
    array(
        "US02",
        "books",
        "Books"
    )
);
```

Or use `USxx` as a key:

```
$categories = array(
    "US01" => array(
        "audio-video",
        "Audio & Video"
    ),
    "US02" => array(
        "books",
        "Books"
    ),
);
```

Comment: In you second array, how do I get the values of the array inside? For example, if provide `US01` how can I get `audio-video` or `Audio & Video` whichever of the two I want? Also, I check for the existence of an array key using `array_key_exists('US01',$categories)`. Is it safe to do so on the second kind of array?

Comment: Is echo $categories['US01'][0]; echo $categories['US01'][1]; the way?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array of arrays:

```
$categories = array (
    "US01" => array("name" => "Audio & Video", "alias" => "audio-video"),
    "US02" => array("name" => "Books", "alias" => "books"),
);
```

Then access it like:

```
echo $categories['US01']['alias']; // audio-video
echo $categories['US01']['name']; // Audio & Video

echo $categories['US02']['alias']; // books
echo $categories['US02']['name']; // Books
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$categories = array (
    "audio-video" => "Audio & Video",
    "books" => "Books",
    "vehicles" => "Vehicles",
    "watches" => "Watches"
);

$newCategories = Array();

$i = 1;
foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {

    $index = "US" . ($i < 10) ? "0" . $i : $i;
    $newCategorys[$index] = Array('slug'=>$categories[$key], 'value'=>$categories[$value]);

    $i++;

}
```

So you can reach everything with

```
$newCategories['US01']['slug'] // for "audio-video "
```

and

```
$newCategories['US01']['value'] // for "Audio & Video"
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

No, not this way, but could do it this way:

```
$categories = array (
    "US01" => array("audio-video" => "Audio & Video"),
    "US02" => array("books" => "Books"),
    "US03" => array("vehicles" => "Vehicles"),
    "US04" => array("watches" => "Watches")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 2-dimensional array if you want.

```
$category = array("US01" => array("audio-video" => "Audio & Video"),
    "US02" => array("books" => "Books"),
    "US03" => array("vehicles" => "Vehicles"),
    "US04" => array("watches" => "Watches")
);
```